# Calling function to save and redirect route: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have following functions in Controller.

```
public function UpdateCountry(\App\Http\Requests\CountryRequest $request) {
    $this->SaveChanges($request);
}

private function SaveChanges($request) {
    if($request['CountryID'] == 0) {
        $Country = new \App\Models\CountryModel();
    }
    else {
        $Country = \App\Models\CountryModel
                  ::where('CountryID', $request['CountryID'])->first();
    }

    $Country->Country = $request['Country'];
    $Country->CountryCode = $request['CountryCode'];
    $Country->save();
    return redirect()->route('AllCountries');
}

public function AllCountries() {
    $Countries = \App\Models\CountryModel::all();
    return view('Country.List', array('Countries' => $Countries));
}
```

Issue is in below line: When I call function SaveChanges, I am not able to see List of countries page and when I write the code directly in UpdateCountry function, it redirect route successfully.

```
return redirect()->route('AllCountries');
```

Anybody faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is being handled by the `UpdateCountry` function. Laravel will take action based on the returned value from this function. However, you're not returning anything from this function.

You call `SaveChanges`, which returns a `Redirect` object, but then you don't return anything from your `UpdateCountry` function. You need that `Redirect` object from the `UpdateCountry` function in order for Laravel to actually return the redirect to the client.

Update your `UpdateCountry` function to this:

```
// added the return statement, so this function will return the redirect
// to the route handler.
public function UpdateCountry(\App\Http\Requests\CountryRequest $request) {
    return $this->SaveChanges($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed a return in $this->SaveChanges($request). It has to be:

```
public function UpdateCountry(\App\Http\Requests\CountryRequest $request) {
    return $this->SaveChanges($request);
}
```

I hope it works fine for you.